# c++ classes can only be passed by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Is there a way I can make my custom class be passed by reference only?

Basically, I have the following class:

```
class A{
private:
  int _x;
public:
  A(int y){
    _x = y;
  }
};
```

Can I make it to where I can ONLY pass it by reference?  And it will throw a compile time error otherwise?

Comment: Yes, make its copy constructor private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several people have suggested making the copy constructor private.  This is a *mostly* good solution to the problem however it's not complete.  It still allows the type itself to accidentally pass itself by value.  A more thorough solution is to declare the copy constructor private and then never implement it.

```
class A{
private:
  // Prevent value copying
  A(const A&);

  int _x;
public:
  A(int y){
    _x = y;
  }
};
```

Note: As @DeadMG points out, in C++11 using `delete` is preferred.

```
A(const A&) = delete;
```

Comment: I never suggested *implementing* the copy constructor.

Answer (score 10):

You can prevent copying by declaring the copy constructor as private (or deleted in C++11).

Comment: Or in pre-C++11 inherit from `boost::noncopyable`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes declaring the copy constructor private (but still implementing it) allows friend functions or friend classes to still use the private function/members of the class, therefore, the copy constructor would still be accessible.  Which is why you declare it private and do not implement it.